# Is there a way to execute a function ONLY if the option of a tkinter optionmenu is changed?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

When using tkinter OptionMenu the command input lets you activate a function, but the same function activates even when you click on the already set option. Example: option "A" is set, you click again on option "A" the command activates, however I would like it to happen only if I change the selection from "A" to another option that isn't "A" like "B" or "C" and viceversa.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

# Create window------------------------------------------
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.geometry("800x500")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Function-----------------------------------------------
def print_message(*args):
    print("the option has been changed")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Dropdown menu------------------------------------------
# Datatype
option_selected = StringVar()  
# Create dropdown menu
option_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
option_selected.set(option_list[0]) 
option_menu = OptionMenu(window, option_selected, *option_list)
option_menu.pack()
option_selected.trace("w",print_message)
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Maintain window open
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `OptionMenu` does not support such feature.  You need to do the checking inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `OptionMenu` does not support such feature, however you can create a custom `OptionMenu` to provide such feature:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class CustomOptionMenu(tk.OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, var, *values, command=None):
        super().__init__(master, var, *values,
                         command=self.on_selected if command else None)
        self.command = command
        self.value = var.get()

    def on_selected(self, value):
        # execute callback only if selected value is changed
        if self.value != value:
            self.command(value)
            self.value = value  # save the selected value

# Create window------------------------------------------
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.geometry("800x500")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Function-----------------------------------------------
def print_message(value):
    print(f"the option has been changed to {value}")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Dropdown menu------------------------------------------
# Datatype
option_selected = tk.StringVar()
# Create dropdown menu
option_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
option_selected.set(option_list[0])
option_menu = CustomOptionMenu(window, option_selected, *option_list, command=print_message)
option_menu.pack()
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Maintain window open
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good answer but I think you can simplify it using a function decorator instead of the class. That will make it easier for OP, if they haven't learned OOP yet.

Comment: @TheLizzard You are welcome to provide answer using function decorator.  For OP case, I don't think it is easier when using function decorator.  From my point of view, function decorator is hard to understand than OOP for beginner.

Comment: Fair point - I didn't learn how to use decorators until I already learned OOP. Tomorrow I will write an answer with a decorator for completeness sake but this answer will probably be more intuitive for most people.

Comment: Thanks a lot @acw1668, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, here is how to do the same thing as @acw1668 but with a function decorator:

```py
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

def only_call_on_arg_change(first):
    def wrapper(command):
        prev_value = first
        def inner(value):
            nonlocal prev_value
            if value != prev_value:
                command(value)
                prev_value = value
        return inner
    return wrapper

# Create window------------------------------------------
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.geometry("800x500")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Function-----------------------------------------------
@only_call_on_arg_change(first="A")
def print_message(*args):
    print("the option has been changed")
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Dropdown menu------------------------------------------
# Datatype
option_selected = StringVar()  
# Create dropdown menu
option_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
option_selected.set(option_list[0]) 
option_menu = OptionMenu(window, option_selected, *option_list, command=print_message)
option_menu.pack()
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Maintain window open
window.mainloop()
```

I used `command=...` when creating the `OptionMenu`, I store the last value, and I only call `command` if the value changed like @acw1668. The reason the `only_call_on_arg_change` function is messy is because unlike @acw1668's solution, I don't have access to the `StringVar` and can't get the default value with `var.get()`. If you stare at @acw1668's solution and mine side by side for long enough, you should be able to see the similarities and figure out how both approaches work.